# How to restore system image backup on windows 10?

Tags: windows, backup, operating-systems

I made a backup of the system image for Windows.

The C: drive was backed up to the D: drive in a folder named WindowsImageBackup.

This folder has the following structure

```
WindowsImageBackup>
   -Desktop-FXXXXX
       -Backup 2019-XX-XX XXXX>
          -Hard Disk Image Files*
       -Catalog
       -Logs
```

How can I restore this image on to the machine?

There was a security update - KB5017699 that is not allowing a critical application to run. I am not able to uninstall this update by force, hence why I am seeking to restore to this previous image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Before proceeding, I would suggest taking a complete system image backup of the current Windows installation using a reliable tool like Macrium Reflect Free edition.)*

- Press the Shift key while you select the Power button, and click Restart. Your PC will restart in the Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) environment.
- Click Advanced startup > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > System Image Recovery.
- On some OEM PCs, you need to use the following route instead:
- Click Advanced startup > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > See more recovery options > System Image Recovery.
- Attach the external hard drive (if the system image is stored there) and finish the process.

[image]

Note: If the above options are missing, then please boot the computer with the Windows 10 USB setup disk to enter WinRE.

References

- [How to Restore System Image Backup in Windows 10 or 11](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-system-image-backup-windows-11/)
- [How to restore your PC from a Windows 10 system image](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-restore-your-pc-from-a-windows-10-system-image)